# Can't control brightness in Ubuntu

Tags: brightness

I have an old desktop with an Acer CPU having Intel graphics card running Ubuntu 14.04 . I can't find a way to adjust the display brightness. I have gone through many threads here and googled many times but no success. Tried xbacklight, indicator-brightness, editing grub file. and my `/sys/class/backlight` is empty.

Answer (score 0):

There may be settings built into your physical monitor's menu but other than than Ubuntu can not control the brightness of any monitors other than a built-in laptop display. Sorry for the inconvenience. Hope this helps!